# Highlight selected image in Windows Phone XAML?

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone

I am currently using the Image control in XAML, when the user taps on the image I want to display another image like a tap effect*, so for example I want to make the image a bit darker or lighter once the user taps on it, how can I do this using the image control?

Comment: Instead of that image in its place or in a popup or in a special page?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, but I want to give like a tap effect, so I basically want the image to become lighter once a user taps on it, I already have both images

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this with adding a new image to the mousebuttonup, mousebuttondown and mouseleave event of the image control

Comment: Bit of a heck!! you could use a button instead, It has all the visual states like pressed, disabled supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a collapsed image with the same size at the same position as the first one. If the user taps the image, you show the previously collapsed image.

If you want to make your first image darker, set the background of your hidden image to black and opacity to 0.25 or something like this. When it gets visible your first image will be slightly darker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead that you can try to customize the style of your button. In Visual State>>Pressed>>You can change the Color or you can give some animation as well.

tHANKS,